# zmq_socket() hangs on eventfd() syscall

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, zeromq

I have a strange case when call to zmq_socket() hangs on eventfd() syscall. I can't find anything in eventfd() documentation about blocking. It should return file descriptor or -1 in case of an error. No waiting for anything. What can cause eventfd() to be blocking? Here is the stack trace:

```
#0  0x00007ff00f41348b in eventfd () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:78
#1  0x00007ff00fc66cce in zmq::make_fdpair (r_=r_@entry=0x7feff002f51c, w_=w_@entry=0x7feff002f518) at src/ip.cpp:338
#2  0x00007ff00fc86e94 in zmq::signaler_t::signaler_t (this=0x7feff002f518) at src/signaler.cpp:121
#3  0x00007ff00fc6ab17 in zmq::mailbox_t::mailbox_t (this=0x7feff002f4b0) at /usr/include/c++/9/bits/atomic_base.h:709
#4  0x00007ff00fc8a9ee in zmq::socket_base_t::socket_base_t (this=0x7feff002ee80, parent_=<optimized out>, tid_=<optimized out>, sid_=<optimized out>, thread_safe_=<optimized out>) at src/socket_base.cpp:252
#5  0x00007ff00fc761c0 in zmq::pair_t::pair_t (this=0x7feff002ee80, parent_=<optimized out>, tid_=<optimized out>, sid_=<optimized out>) at src/pair.cpp:37
#6  0x00007ff00fc87b27 in zmq::socket_base_t::create (type_=type_@entry=0, parent_=parent_@entry=0x5641ed59de10, tid_=232, sid_=232) at src/socket_base.cpp:151
#7  0x00007ff00fc56ebc in zmq::ctx_t::create_socket (this=0x5641ed59de10, type_=0) at src/ctx.cpp:380
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve], please! As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.